# Making a password work

Tags: nsis

So what you gave me works great. 
Now the question is how do I set it so the password page has a message on it asking for you to inter your password This is what I have so far.

```
Function leave 


    ${NSD_GetText} $hwnd $0
    ${If} $0 != "web9^root"
        MessageBox MB_OK "Please enter a valid security code"
        Abort
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
Function pre
nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $dialog

${NSD_CreatePassword} 0 0 50% 8% ""
    Pop $hwnd


nsDialogs::show

FunctionEnd
```

======================

so i have the following script set up to run,

```
!include "nsDialogs.nsh" 
!include "winmessages.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"
OutFile "test.exe"



Page Custom pre

var dialog
var hwnd

Function pre
nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $dialog
${NSD_CreatePassword} 0 0 50% 8% "web9^root"
    Pop $hwnd
    SendMessage $hwnd ${EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR} 149 0 # 149 = medium dot

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Section ""
SectionEnd
```

How do I make it so that if you do not know the password it will not let you pass. I also need to know who to set it so that the password is not already in the text feild. Can you all help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to add a leave function for that nsdialogs page...

```
Page custom pre leave
```

...and there you verify the password...

```
Function leave
    ${NSD_GetText} $hwnd $0
    ${If} $0 != "yourPassword"
        MessageBox MB_OK "Wrong password"
        Abort
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

if you don't want the password in that field, just leave it empty when creating the dialog!

Comment: So what you gave me works great. Now the question is how do I set it so the password page has a message on it asking for you to inter your password